# Expectation of product of stochastic integral and random variable with end-point dependence

Tags: brownian-motion, expected-value, stochastic-integrals

Consider stochastic processes $X_t$, $\sigma_t$, and Wiener process $W_t$, with $X_t$ independent of $\sigma_s$ $\forall t, s$, and $W_t$ independent of $\sigma_s$ $\forall t, s$, but where $X_t$ and $W_s$ are independent $\forall t \neq s$. Also, $\mathbb{E} X_t = 0$. What is the value of the expression:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} X_T \int_0^T \sigma_t dW_t
\end{equation}

Clearly, the only part of the integral exhibiting dependency with $X_T$ is the end-point $W_T$. Does this prevent me from separating the expression into $\mathbb{E} X_T \mathbb{E} \int_0^T \sigma_t dW_t$?

Comment: Yes, it does prevent you from separating. Just consider $\sigma=1$ and $X_t = W_t$

Comment: Hey @saz I've had the same idea, but in that case dependence between $X_t$ and the integrator is not only contemporaneous right?

Comment: Well, that would be easier to answer if the OP would provide us with a definition of "contemporaneous dependence".

Comment: I am just guessing, but I seems to me that he assuming that $X_t$ is independent from $W_s$ $\forall t\neq s$.

Comment: @saz Thanks for responding. I'll edit the question to give a precise definition of contemporaneous dependence, but it is exactly as RScrlli suggests.

Comment: @Rscrlli thanks for responding. Yes that's correct I'll edit the question.

Comment: @ColinTBowers If they are independent for $s \neq t$, then it follows quite immediately from the continuity of Brownian motion that $X_t$ and $W_t$ are independent (e.g. using the characterization via characteristic functions). So I don't really see your point in the definition of  contemporaneous dependence

Comment: @saz I think I see. Does this mean that for a meaningful expression I would instead need to define dependence in terms of the Brownian increments?

Comment: @saz ... and the answer appears to be fairly obvious if dependence is defined in terms of Brownian increments. If you put together a short answer indicating the type of dependence defined in the question is not feasible, then I'll mark it answered and upvote. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two random variables $X$ and $W$ are independent if the sigma algebras $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(W)$ are independent sigma algebras. 
Then under your assumptions we could say that 
$\sigma(X_s)$ is independent of $\sigma(W_t)$ for all $t<s$, then  $\sigma(X_s)$ must be independent of $\bigcap_{t<s} \sigma(W_t)$.

But by continuity of the Wiener processes we have that 
$\bigcap_{t<s} \sigma(W_t)= \sigma(W_s)$.